# Terraform azurerm_role_definition with assignable_scope in Azure DevOps parameterized

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have create the following custom role definition in Azure using Terraform and AzureDevOps. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_definition

It's working well with the hardcoded subscription ids as assignable_scopes and now I wanted to parametrize this part. (see the commented part in the script)

In order to parameterize the assignable_scopes ,  the user will give as input in an Azure DevOps variable the following text: `"/subscriptions/****1","/subscriptions/****2"`.

Then in Terraform I have declared a variable to read the input above and assigned it in the role definition below as: `assignable_scopes = [var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids]`:

```
variable "assignable_scopes_subs_ids" {
  description = "Assignable scopes from Key Vault"
  type        = list
  default     = [""]
}


   resource "azurerm_role_definition" "terraform_role_data_science" {
      name        = "Data-Labeler"
      scope       = data.azurerm_subscription.dev.id
      description = "Can label data for Labeling"
      permissions {
        actions     = [
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/read",
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/projects/read",
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/labels/write"
            ]
        not_actions = [
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/projects/summary/read"
            ]
      }
      assignable_scopes = [var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids]
             # [   "/subscriptions/****1", #Subscription1  hardcoded like this is working
             #   "/subscriptions/****2",  #Subscription2 hardcoded like this is working
             #   "/subscriptions/****3" ]  #Subscription3 hardcoded like this is working
      
    }
```

Unfortunatelly this will throw an error when running the terraform validation in the pipeline.
What input is required so that the role_definition will succeed like in the case of the hardcoded version of assignable_scopes ? How can this be successfuly parameterized?

[image]

Comment: `var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids` is already a list. try this `assignable_scopes = var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids`

Comment: thank you, I have tried this also and it will throw an error in the plan when running:  -input=false -out=tfplan -var=assignable_scopes_subs_ids=/subscriptions/***,/subscriptions/***  Invalid expression

  on <value for var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token

Comment: well, either make your variable a string (and input like this) or make it a list and input it as one... dont mix string and list

Comment: yes, you are right.  I want to declare the variable as a list. Check. What input should I give and how can I assign the variable so that it will be hcl conform?

Comment: try `-var=assignable_scopes_subs_ids=['/subscriptions/***','/subscriptions/***']`

Comment: Single quotes are not valid. Use double quotes (") to enclose strings.   When using double quotes  Invalid expression on <value for var.assignable_scopes_subs_ids> line 1:
  (source code not available)  Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Answer (score 0):

I have added something similar to below .

```
variable "assignable_scopes_subs_ids" {
  description = "Assignable scopes from Key Vault"
  type        = list
  default     = [""]
}

locals { 
  sub_ids = [for sub_id in var.assignable_scopes_subs_id : sub_id]
    }

   resource "azurerm_role_definition" "terraform_role_data_science" {
      name        = "Data-Labeler"
      scope       = data.azurerm_subscription.dev.id
      description = "Can label data for Labeling"
      permissions {
        actions     = [
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/read",
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/projects/read",
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/labels/write"
            ]
        not_actions = [
            "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/labeling/projects/summary/read"
            ]
      }
      assignable_scopes = [local.subs_ids]
               
    }
```